# sqlite select with condition on date

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, date

I have an sqlite table with Date of Birth. I would like to execute a query to select those records where the age is more than 30.
I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
select * from mytable where dob > '1/Jan/1980'
select * from mytable where dob > '1980-01-01'
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Some thing like this could be used:

```
select dateofbirth from customer Where DateofBirth  BETWEEN date('1004-01-01') AND date('1980-12-31');  
select dateofbirth from customer where date(dateofbirth)>date('1980-12-01');
select * from customer where date(dateofbirth) < date('now','-30 years');
```

**If you are using Sqlite V3.7.12 or greater**

Dont use `date(dateofbirth)` just use `dateofbirth`. So your query would look like this:

```
select * from customer where dateofbirth < date('now','-30 years');
```

Comment: All those who come here from google: now it doesn't work anymore with sqlite v3.7.12; don't use `date(dateofbirth)`, just `dateofbirth` would be good.

Comment: Just need to be careful with one thing: ```date(field) > date('2018-05-20')``` and ```field > '2018-05-20'``` returns different results for me so using function ```date()``` is the only way how it works correctly for me **if the field is not Date but DateTime**.

Answer (score 26):

Using the magic docs at [the sqlite website](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
select * from mytable where dob < date('now','-30 years');
```

Answer (score 5):

Try writing using the date format 'YYYY-MM-DD'

```
select * from mytable where dob > '1980-01-01'
```

A more programic way would be something like this:

```
select * from mytable where datediff(dob, now()) > 30
```

You'll Need to find specific syntax for sqlite.

Comment: Back in 2010 `select * from mytable where dob > '1980-01-01'` might not work, but currently this command works perfectly on `sqlite3`.

Comment: Sqlite says *`Error (1): no such function: now`* and *`Error (1): no such function: datediff`*.

Answer (score 0):

select * from mytable where date(dob) > date('1980-01-10')

Answer (score 0):

QLite3 has some cool new date functions. Per the [docs site](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) you can use **date()**, **time()**, **datetime()**, **julianday()**, **unixepoch()**, or **strftime()** depending on how your column data is formatted.

If you use **strftime()**, like my suggestion below, then you have to make sure that your column data is formatted the same way as your strftime string.

You would probably want something like:

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE dob < strftime("%m/%d/%Y", 'now', '-30 year');`

Note that you might have to change the format string here to match your own.

---

And here's some code that I use personally to give you a better idea of how powerful it is. It lets me get all the orders from the previous 3 months, not including this month.

`SELECT * FROM orders WHERE SHIPPEDDATE > strftime('%m/%d/%Y', 'now', 'start of month', '-3 month');`

The modifiers are very powerful with sqlite. The first string inside **strftime()** is the format, the 2nd string is when you want the date to start. 'Start of month' puts the day to 1, and '-3 month' goes back 3 months. So if I ran that today (08/03/2022), the date it uses would be 05/01/2022.