# Sqlite WHERE condition on JULIAN dates?

Tags: sql, sqlite, air, system.data.sqlite, julian-date

**How to build a sql where clause on a Julian column date?**

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE JulianDateColumn > ?
```

I can't build a working statement I got either no results with a GreaterThan ">" operator or everything with a SmallerThan "<"

I tried with parameters letting Air (Adobe) handle it. 
I also tried without parameters with string [(because of this post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309227/sqlite-select-with-condition-on-date):

```
JulianDateColumn > '2010-04-02 02:02:02'
```

or date object

```
JulianDateColumn > date('now')
```

All example that I have been able to found, works for date in string (TEXT column) or Unix Time (INTEGER column)

And **I can't store my date in any other formats than Julian** for compatibility reasons...

Comment: Shhh***t how do I remove a question...?

ANSWER to my problem :

    SELECT * FROM Products WHERE JulianDateColumn > julianday('now') -1

And wow! It worked!

Please excuse my stupid tired brain! At least building the question has helped me see the obvious! I post the answer here since I dont have enough reputation to answer my question within the next 7 hours.

Comment: Answering your own question is quite ok. You can select your answer if that is the best (or only :-) one. And perhaps delete your (not so nicely formulated) comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER to my problem :

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE JulianDateColumn > julianday('now') -1
```

And wow! It worked!

At least building the question has helped me see the obvious!

Comment: I would like too but I always have to wait few hours to be able to.