# getAll from sqlite database android

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite, datetime

I want to make a memo which was dated, I input the date with activities in a separate place from the calendar. How do I display all events in the calendar according to the date that I fed?

```
public List<Foto> getAllFotoList() {
        List<Foto> fotoList = new ArrayList<Foto>();

        String query_tb_foto = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FOTO;

        // SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query_tb_foto, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                // Siswa siswa = new Siswa(cursor.getString(0),
                // cursor.getString(1));
                Foto foto = new Foto(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow("COL_JUDULFT")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow("COL_IMG")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow("COL_DESFT")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow("COL_STARTDATEFT")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow("COL_STARTTIMEFT")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow("COL_ENDDATEFT")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow("COL_ULANGFT")),
                        cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow("COL_ALARMFT")));
                fotoList.add(foto);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            return fotoList;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Is this true? Thanks for respons.

Comment: Are you trying to only select certain dates from a SQLite database table?

Comment: Yes. I want to scrap at the appropriate date. Can you help me?

Comment: Is it wrong if I use the `List` to display the date?

Comment: I posted an answer that should help you out. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Avoid using List class, if you do not know in advance about data set. Use SimpleCursorAdapter instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like `SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE date('1990-01-01');` (Just insert your custom date). This should return all of the results from your table with the same date value. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309227/sqlite-select-with-condition-on-date) for further explanation and the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to see what else you can do with dates.

Two answer your second question, using a `ListView` should be fine. I personally use an `ArrayList` to populate my `ListView`s for `SQLite` results since queries return an arbitrary number of results. An `ArrayList` makes it easy to store and access those results.

Answer (score 0):

did you sore the date as a GMTTIMESTAMP?
if so

```
 String Q= "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_FOTO +" ORDER BY GMTTIMESTAMP DESC;";
```

will put all the rows of the data with the most recent at the front.

or you could reference it by your primary key?

I was always told to make sure you remember to put a semicolon in side the brackets or your leave yourself open to SQL injections.

and you always want to check for null cursors so you should also have

`if(cursor!=null&&cursor.moveToFirst()){}`

Comment: So this query `String Q= "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_FOTO +" ORDER BY GMTTIMESTAMP DESC;";` call the columns `COL_STARTDATEFT` of my table `TABLE_FOTO` ??

Comment: Do I need to add some code in my calendar menu? I'm confused by the logic of the algorithm :)

Comment: are COL_STARTDATEFT or COL_STARTTIMEFT timestamps or strings, so did you enter them as "currentSystemTime()"(which is a gmttimestamp something like 103774000) or are you string them as strings?