# date greater than a specified date (date, month, year)

Tags: sql, sqlite

For a database table containing int fields date, month and year, what is the best way to query rows greater than a specified date?

Comment: what DB implementation (i.e. Oracle, MySQL?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sqlite select with condition on date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2309227/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
select dateofbirth from customer Where DateofBirth  BETWEEN date('1004-01-01') AND date('1980-12-31');  

select dateofbirth from customer where date(dateofbirth)>date('1980-12-01');

select * from customer where date(dateofbirth) < date('now','-30 years');
```

See [sqlite select with condition on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309227/sqlite-select-with-condition-on-date/2309915#2309915)

Answer (score 1):

With simple arithmetic, you can make a selection like this:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE year*10000+month*100+day>20131021;
```

Comment: Even though there is a better answer than yours for the Android platform, I find your answer useful for the server code for which I will be using your query. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @SandahAung Humm... This solution is lightweight - doesn't involve much logic neither function calls - and deals with "int fields". How does accepted solution apply???

Comment: The accepted solution looks better to my boss who tends to prefer function calls to programmer-supplied code. (He thinks API functions are cleaner and less err0r-prone.) The boss who oversees server-side coders doesn't mind though so I'm using your code on the server side.