# Query filtering based on dates using FMDB?

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, ios7, fmdb

How do I query games that are after a "visible" date?
The dateformat is set:

```
FMDatabase *db = self.database;
if([self.database open]){
    [db beginTransaction];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-dd-MM'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
    [db setDateFormat:formatter];
    ...
}
```

The table is created the following way:

```
[db executeUpdate:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS game (gameId Varchar(36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,name TEXT,visibleFrom TEXT)"];
```

The query is executed the following way:

```
FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM game WHERE game.visibleFrom >= ?,[NSDate date]];
```

This returns nothing. When I use `select * from game` then i get all the games. But I need the filtered result. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the SQLite syntax for querying dates: [sqlite select with condition on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309227/sqlite-select-with-condition-on-date)
You might need something like '@" ... where date > date(?)", formattedDate', where formattedDate is formatted like '1980-12-31'