# Cannot retrieve database record using WHERE on DATE column of SQLite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am developing a tutorial project and working with SQLite database. I am trying to retrieve records using `WHERE` on `DATE` column in database. But it is retrieving nothing. What is wrong with my code ?

The `CREATE` statement in **database helper class**

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                                + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," 
                                + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT," 
                                + COLUMN_DATE + " DATE,"
                                + COLUMN_DONE + " BOOLEAN)";
```

This is how I am **retrieving record**

```
String date = "04-22-2014";
ArrayList<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
db = getReadableDatabase();
String query = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME + " where "+ COLUMN_DATE + " = "+ date;
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
{
    do{
        Task task = new Task();
        task.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        task.setDescription(cursor.getString(1));
        task.setDate(cursor.getString(2));
        task.setDone(Boolean.valueOf(cursor.getString(3)));
        tasks.add(task);
    }
    while(cursor.moveToFirst());
}

return tasks;
```

But it is not returning any record.

Comment: Make sure you have data inside your database, especially data matching that date.

Comment: Notice that Sql dates will not be equal if the time is different (i.e the same date but different times). If you want to just compare by date without time, you should cast to date only

Comment: Sqlite Date data type also store time along with date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get datas from sqlite database based on Date.You need to use standard format of date while inserting data and retrieving data based on date.The standard date foramt is YYYY-MM-DD.
For more info:https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

try this..

```
String date = "2014-04-22";
```

instead of

```
String date = "04-22-2014";
```

where while saving date in sqlite you need to format the as above mentioned.

**Date and Time Datatype**

SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of **SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values**:

**TEXT** as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").

**REAL** as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.

**INTEGER** as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and time functions.

Comment: Yes I inserted using that format and retrieving using that format.

Comment: use TEXT instead of using DATE .try this.... "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+COLUMN_DESCRIPTION+" TEXT,"+
    COLUMN_DATE+" TEXT,"+COLUMN_DONE+" BOOLEAN)";

Comment: for supported datatypes in sqlite refer this...https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: So it means. Whenever I store date, it is recommanded to use TEXT only ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME + " where "+ COLUMN_DATE + " = "+ "'"+date+"'";
```

Comment: have you checked data in db is it there?

Comment: Yes data is inside the db

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309227/sqlite-select-with-condition-on-date