# How to properly query/format dates

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to build a function for my SQlite database using python. The purpose of the function is to pull any date under the calibration_date field that is 1 to 5 days away from the current date.

I've tried messing with my format on the table itself, thinking it was a formatting issue. The function still pulls nothing.

```
def datecheck():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("Calibration_Monitor.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT Serial, Calibration_Date from Masterlog where date(Calibration_Date) < (SELECT DATETIME('now', '+5 days'))")
    print(cur.fetchall())
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Hoping someone can help me solve this mystery!

Anything helps :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sqlite select with condition on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309227/sqlite-select-with-condition-on-date)

Comment: what do you mean `calibration_date field that is 1 to 5 days away from the current`. calibration_date is past or future date??? If pas date then you should subtract 5 days from current date and then compare with the DB dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reference the date without `date()` if the column is formatted as a date column but use `date(Calibration_Date)` if it is not.

Also to get the second portion you don't need the extra `SELECT` in there.  See below for a fix and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309915/10366273) for more information.

```
def datecheck():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("Calibration_Monitor.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT Serial, Calibration_Date FROM Masterlog WHERE Calibration_Date < date('now', '+5 days')")
    print(cur.fetchall())
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Now if what you meant is dates `BETWEEN` 1 and 5 days away, and not *any date* under 5 days away, you would want to use something like:

```
cur.execute("SELECT Serial, Calibration_Date FROM Masterlog WHERE Calibration_Date BETWEEN date('now') AND date('now', '+5 days')")
```

**Edit:**
If you intend for dates in the past and not dates in the future, you should change it to `+5 days`.

Comment: i think `-5` because date should be in past.

Comment: I think it's something like a calendar function where he wants to know of things coming up within the next 5 days, and therefore dates are in the future meaning +5 is actually correct.

Comment: Okay got you. Awesome then

Answer (score 0):

Use `-5` NOT `+5` if your Calibration_Date date is past date. (Based on my comment above). This will give you all the records older than 5 days in the past.

```
.......where date(Calibration_Date) < date('now','-5 day')
```

Something like:

```
SELECT Serial, Calibration_Date from Masterlog where date(Calibration_Date) < date('now','-5 day')
```

If you want **last five days** data

```
SELECT Serial, Calibration_Date FROM Masterlog WHERE Calibration_Date BETWEEN date('now') AND date('now', '-5 days')
```