# How to store and query dates in SQLite - using DB browser for Sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite, date

Not sure which data type and formatting to use when storing dates in my tables in DB browser for SQLite. Also not sure how to format the SQL queries when retrieving the data. For instance I've created a films database with an attribute for Release (as text data type), I want to be able to find films between two dates.

table : films
+-------+------------+-------------+
|   id  |   title    |   Release   |
+-------+------------+-------------+
|   1   | Star Wars  | 2000-01-01  |
|   2   | Star Trek  | 2010-01-01  |

tried:

SELECT *
FROM tblFilms
WHERE Release BETWEEN (2000-01-01 AND 2010-01-01)

This does not return any values

Comment: Please revise your question according to these guidelines https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/

Comment: Your query does not return results because you do not enclose the 2 dates inside single quotes.

Comment: Also remove the parentheses:  `SELECT * FROM tblFilms WHERE Release BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2010-01-01'`

Comment: Your first operation selected dates between 1998 and 2008, and probably not even interpreted these as a year. The dates became calculations. This is why date values should be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

It's indiffernent if the following is from DB Browser for SQLite, or the SQLite terminal itself. The software is just a frontend.

**Storing dates** can be done in principle in any form, *as SQLite is not typed*, but natively SQLite works with one of these formats:

- text in a subset of the ISO-8601 format: `2022-09-17 23:34:08`
- Julian day : `2459840.40688294`
- Seconds since (or before) 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (the unix timestamp). : `1663451396`

See [documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for SQLite dates.

**Queries** on dates, and limiting results,  is [explained with examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309227/sqlite-select-with-condition-on-date).

**Formatting results** can be done using `strftime`:

```sql
select strftime("%m/%d/%Y", "2022-09-17") as 'US DATE'
```

returns
`09/17/2022`